# How to autofill values in other boxes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to autofill the other boxes with calculated values when one of the box is filled with a value. For example:[image: Box Fields]

When I fill the '*meter*' value, the value in '*feet*', and '*centimeter*' should get auto-filled with respective values.
And same for the other values.
I couldn't come up with any idea or code (In **Flutter**) . Please give some help with code, plugins or extensions.

Comment: please share your code, what you have done?

Comment: I couldn't come up with any code. I am stuck with ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick example on how to achieve what you want, just using plain `TextFormField` widgets with its own `TextEditingController`'s.

The enum `UnitType` will help you out figuring which field was actually modified and update the others accordingly.

[image]

```
enum UnitType {
  meter,
  cm,
  feet,
}

class ConvertWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ConvertWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController _feetController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController _cmController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController _meterController = TextEditingController(text: '0');

  void _convertUnit(UnitType type) {
    double? ft = double.tryParse(_feetController.value.text) ?? 0;
    double? cm = double.tryParse(_cmController.value.text) ?? 0;
    double? meter = double.tryParse(_meterController.value.text) ?? 0;

    switch (type) {
      case UnitType.feet:
        _meterController.text = (ft * 0.3048).toString();
        _cmController.text = (ft * 100).toString();
        break;

      case UnitType.cm:
        _meterController.text = (cm / 100).toString();
        _feetController.text = (cm * 0.03048).toString();
        break;

      case UnitType.meter:
        _cmController.text = (meter * 100).toString();
        _feetController.text = (meter * 0.3048).toString();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: _feetController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (_) => _convertUnit(UnitType.feet),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Feet'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _cmController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (_) => _convertUnit(UnitType.cm),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'CM'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _meterController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (_) => _convertUnit(UnitType.meter),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Meter'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem though, I cannot immediately start putting values in the text fields, I need to press twice and then delete the Zeros '0', and then I can put some values. After a single tap it's not taking any input. What possibly can the problem be?